# Isospin Triplet and Spin Singlet Relationship

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, isospin-symmetry

Why does the isospin triplet correspond to a spin singlet when observing a nuclei? Similarly, why is a isospin singlet correspond to a spin triplet for the same system? Is there a physical meaning to this?

Comment: Could you perhaps give a bit more context?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632247/2451